# Como fazer um loop de um custom post type seguindo o menu_order?

Tags: wordpress, loop, order

Em uma página estática no wordpress estou fazendo o loop de um custom post type de uma lista de serviços da seguinte forma:

```
$temp = $wp_query;  
$wp_query = null;  
$wp_query = new WP_Query();  
$wp_query->query('showposts=14&post_type=servicos'.'&paged='.$paged);  

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();  

the_excerpt('');  

endwhile;  

$wp_query = null;  
$wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
```

Ao lado carrego uma lista de especialidades através do código abaixo:

```
wp_list_categories('taxonomy=Servicos&title_li=');
```

Ambos eu precisava ordenar seguindo a ordem da coluna menu_order na tabela wp_posts. Como poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você esta precisando dar uma olhada documentação do WordPress, pois na página de referencia para [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) estão documentados os parâmetros de `order_by` onde você pode usar `menu_order`, além que a forma que você esta fazendo essa query usando a global `$wp_query` não é o correto.
Outra coisa errada é que `showposts` esta [obsoleta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) desde a versão [2.1 do WordPress](http://wordpress.org/news/2007/01/ella-21/) que saiu em Janeiro de 2007...

Aqui o código de como deveria ser seguindo os standards do WordPress:

```php
$new_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 14,
    'post_type'      => servicos,
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
    'paged'          => $paged
) );

while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : $new_query->the_post();  

the_excerpt('');  

endwhile;  
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Já para `wp_list_categories()` não existe uma forma de ordenar por `menu_order`, veja os [parâmetros](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Parameters) aceitos pela função na documentação e perceba que `menu_order` é apenas para posts e não para os termos da sua taxonomia, no caso para taxonomias é possível usar `term_order`, entretanto a para usar `term_order` é necessário trabalhar com `wp_get_object_terms()` que aceita ele como [parâmetro](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms#Argument_Options).

Comment: Amigo, era isso que eu precisava. Obrigado pela explicação bem detalhada. Meu ajudou muito. Valeu! Sucesso!!